# .Net 6 - Diacritics removal failed

Tags: c#, .net, string, diacritics, normalize

I have an issue removing diacritics from an filename provided by FrontEnd.
I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) where it solved the problem.

BUT! ^^

It's not doing the job for me on all my Backend Application.
We are in .net 6 architecture and on a console application based from standard microsoft template it work well...

Standalone console application run on Windows architecture meanwhile our project run on linux docker.

Does anyone have an idea why there is a difference?

Issue:
It remove the diacritics instead of replacing it
I mean the "é" char when normalizing does not split into 2 char ("e" & "'") but keep it at 233 Ascii range

**Exemple:**

my filename contains Diacritics "Rémi.pdf" and use this:

```
mystring.RemoveDiacritics().RemoveNonAscii();

public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string text)
{
    string text2 = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(text2.Length);
    foreach (char c in text2)
    {
        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}

public static string RemoveNonAscii(this string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, "[^\\u0000-\\u007F]+", string.Empty);
}
```

Resolved:
Add this 2 lines in docker file

- RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
- RUN apk add --no-cache icu-data-full

Add false
in csproj

Comment: Why are you trying to remove diacritics in the first place? Neither .NET nor databases have any issues with them. If you want accent-insensitive searches in a database, use an accent-insensitive collation

Comment: I put this [in a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BxzGX3) but there it works, so what is the problem? Also I don't understand what you mean by "it remove the diacritics caused of no replacing." Please rewrite this to make it more clear. Please also give multiple examples of input + actual output + desired output.

Comment: What is the environment in which you are trying to run this code? If you are running it in a Linux-based OS you may need to install ICU libs onto your OS.

Comment: Hello there
i edit the post

Comment: I insert a file into S3 container with filename in header. I need this filename without ascii extanded value
My struggle is that the code i use work in a console application but not on our web api project.
Our Pod are on linux based, alpine docker

Comment: Try adding these lines into your docker file :`RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-data-full`

Comment: Thanks @Eldar
I'm wondering why .net app does not have same result on different architecture. Can you explain to me?
I understand unicode is a standard but why linux is not based on meanwhile windows are... 
Thanks

Comment: Well, moving from 5.0 to 6.0 .NET framework switched to the ICU libs on UNIX environment I thought that might be related to your issue.

Comment: Ok we use alpine image and related to this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/container-images#images-suitable-for-globalization)
maybe u're right.
Our devops added this 2 lines but same result. Maybe i'm missing another thing!
I think u are right regardless this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) 
I just don't know why it's not solved

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to add setting in the `.csproj` file `<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>` to the `PropertyGroup` element.

Comment: Many Thanks @Eldar